# Galois theory - proving two fields are equivalent

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory, extension-field

> Define by $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega)$ to be the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$ along with elements $\alpha,\omega$. Now let $\alpha=\sqrt[6]{5}$ and $\omega=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega),\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\omega^2,\omega^5),\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\omega^4,\omega^5)$ are in fact the same field.

Attempt: Since $\alpha,\omega\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega)$, we have that any product is also in this field. For instance, $\omega^2\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega)$ and $\alpha\omega^2\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega)$. Similarly $\omega^5\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega)$. So the first field is contained in the second. We now need to show the reverse, that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\omega^2,\omega^5)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega)$.

I have no idea how to do this. In fact I am not even sure my first set of working is correct. How do we do this?

Comment: What you proved is not $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\omega^2,\omega^5)$ but $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\omega^2,\omega^5)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega).$ To prove the converse inclusion, just show that $\alpha$ and $\omega$ are products of powers (with exponents $\in\mathbb Z$) of $\alpha\omega^2$ and $\omega^5.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I'm a bit confused, how did I prove that implication? And for the converse inclusion, how would one show that $\alpha=(\alpha\omega^2)^a(\omega^5)^b$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: For your first question, remember the definition of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\omega^2,\omega^5)$ as "the smallest [etc.]". For the 2nd, take $a=1$ and find $b$ s.t. $\omega^{2+5b}=1$ (first, find an integer $d>0$ s.t. $\omega^d=1$).

Comment: @AnneBauval do we require $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$? Surely they should be elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ since our field extension is rational?

Comment: The (here rational) elements of the ground field have nothing to do with the (necessarily integral) exponents which allow to prove that $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\omega^2,\omega^5)$. But before, did you find some integer $d>0$ s.t. $\omega^d=1$? (then you will be able to find $b$ in $\mathbb Z$, and even in $\mathbb N$).

Comment: Can you notice directly that $-\omega$ is one of the cube roots of unity? That should help you out without any difficulty.